# Formula: BlankValue function with CASE function

Tags: formula-field

I am trying CASE function inside a BlankValue function and I'm having trouble with the second expression (the substitute one). The first expression works fine with the case function, but the substitute expression would only return the "else result" of the case function..

Here's my formula:

```
BlankValue( CASE(TEXT(Nombre_de_la_Entidad_r.Subtipo_c), 
                   "Municipio", "Municipio", 
                   "Gobierno Provincial", "Gobierno", 
                   "Gobierno Nacional", "Gobierno", 
                   "Empresa Internacional", "Empresa", 
                   "Empresa Nacional", "Empresa", "-"),    
            CASE(TEXT(Nombre_de_la_Entidad__r.Type), 
                    "Empresa", "Empresa", 
                    "Cooperativa de recicladores", "Institución / Organización",
                    "Organización de la Sociedad Civil", "Institución / Organización",
                    "Universidad", "Institución / Organización", 
                    "Gobierno", "Gobierno", 
                    "Consultor", "-", 
                    "Participante individual", "-", "-"))
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: The second one will return `-` for `Consultor`, `Participante individual`, and no match. Is that what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it could be replaced by another value like 0, or whatever. The thing is even if I try for instance "Universidad" it will pull "-" instead...

Comment: Actually, I have just realized the "-" belongs to the first expression of the BlankValue function...

Answer (score 1):

I think this'll fix it.  The very last value of a CASE statment is the value that is to be returned if **NONE** of the case-values match the CompareTo-value.

Note:  Adding the spaces makes it really easy to see what parameters belong to which functions.

```
BlankValue( 
    CASE(
        TEXT(Nombre_de_la_Entidad_r.Subtipo_c), 
            "Municipio", "Municipio", 
             "Gobierno Provincial", "Gobierno", 
             "Gobierno Nacional", "Gobierno", 
             "Empresa Internacional", "Empresa", 
             "Empresa Nacional", "Empresa", 
             "-"
     ),    
     CASE(   
         TEXT(Nombre_de_la_Entidad__r.Type), 
             "Empresa", "Empresa", 
             "Cooperativa de recicladores", "Institución / Organización",
             "Organización de la Sociedad Civil", "Institución / Organización",
             "Universidad", "Institución / Organización", 
             "Gobierno", "Gobierno", 
             "Consultor", "-", 
             "Participante individual","-"
             "-"
      )
)
```

Comment: Ah I do wish Salesforce would have a "pretty print my formula" button! :) +1

Comment: I can't believe it took em til Winter '13 (?) to get a `monospace` font for formulas

Comment: @amatorVitae: I think there's one other thing here: The first case shouldn't have the `-`; shouldn't its default value be the second CASE? If Subtipo_c is blank, it returns `-`, and then Blankvalue returns `-`.

Comment: yup, edited.  i missed the end of the first CASE and had to lookup BLANKVALUE to make sure the parameters were correct.

Comment: hmmm, i'm not sure if my code makes **business sense**.  the basic jist of getting it to work is in my answer though

Comment: Thanks! I think I got the case function, but it only seems to work with the first expression of the BLANKVALUE. The purpose of using the BLANKVALUE is because I'm comparing values from a picklist (Nombre_de_la_Entidad__r.Type) and its depending picklist (Nombre_de_la_Entidad_r.Subtipo_c)

Comment: I bet a page to format formulas like http://jsonlint.com/ would go down well in the community? Better still a browser plugin... ;-)